# focus and blur with mat-slider

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this html code

```
<mat-slider #slider class="wba-toolbar-slider pl-2"
       (focus)="sliderSelectOnOff(true)" (blur)="sliderSelectOnOff(false)">
</mat-slider>
```

and this code in the associated component.ts file

```
sliderSelectOnOff(value) {
    console.log('sliderSelectOnOff', value);
    this.sliderSelect.emit(value);
}
```

I would expect that when I select and de-select the slider, I would see the output in the console log, but I do not. Any ideas what I am doing or assuming wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`MatSlider` doesn't have `focus()` or `blur()` action outputs in its [API](https://material.angular.io/components/slider/api). These are methods, meaning you can invoke them to blur or focus the host element, but they don't create an output.

I think what you want is `change()`, which is an action output on MatSlider.

```
<mat-slider #slider class="wba-toolbar-slider pl-2"
       [(ngModel)]="value"
       (change)="sliderSelectOnOff()">
</mat-slider>
```

And in your component:

```
sliderSelectOnOff() {
    console.log('sliderSelectOnOff', value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! It turns out I was just working in the wrong HTML and component files.

Despite the lack of documentation `(blur)` and `(focus)` actually did work as expected for me with angular 11.0.9

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was my own error. (I was working in the wrong files).

Oddly despite the lack of reference on angular's official documentation for MatSlider's [API](https://material.angular.io/components/slider/api), `(blur)` and `(focus)` behave as expected with Angular 11.0.9

Comment: Interesting, good to hear 